OnClick EventListener not working in my code
I am trying to execute code when a button is pressed.  I currently have the "catch all" alert set up.
My HTML code
<body  style="overflow:hidden;" >
   <div class="addCustomerMain main">
      <h1>Add Customer</h1>
      <hr>
      <form method="post" id="addCustomer">
         <div class="formContent">
            <div class="formElement">
               <label for="custName">Name</label>
               <input class="txtLarge" type="text" name="custName" id="custName">
            </div>
         </div>
         <div class="formContent">
            <div class="formElement">
               <label for="custAddress">Address</label>
               <input class="txtLarge" type="text" name="custAddress" id="custAddress">
            </div>
         </div>
         <div class="formContent">
            <div class="formElement">
               <label for="custCity">City</label>
               <input class="txtSmall" type="text" name="custCity" id="custCity">
            </div>
            <div class="formElement">
               <label for="custState">State</label>
               <input class="txtXSmall" type="text" name="custState" id="custState">
            </div>
            <div class="formElement">
               <label for="custZip">Zip</label>
               <input class="txtXSmall" type="text" name="custZip" id="custZip">
            </div>
         </div>
         <div class="formContent">
            <div class="formElement">
               <label for="custPhone">Phone</label>
               <input type="text" name="custPhone" id="custPhone" class="txtLarge">
            </div>
         </div>
      </form>
      <div class="formContent" id="divCheckInSubmit">
         <div class="formElement">
            <button id="btnCheckInSubmit" class="btnSubmit">Add Customer</button>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
   <script src="../js/addCustomer.js" defer></script>
</body>


My Javascript
$(document).ready(function() {
    //bulk submit handler This section works when this form is shown.  In this instance, I have the form
    //I currently have the form hidden
    $("#bulkSubmit").submit(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var form = $(this);
        var frmUrl = form.attr('action')

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: frmUrl,
            data: form.serialize()
        });
    });


});

addButton = document.getElementById('btnCheckInSubmit');
addButton.addEventListener("click", function() {
    alert("clicked");
});

The code I want to work, works if I comment out the JQuery for the bulksubmit, but if it is still in there, the checkinsubmit button's eventlister for "click" does not fire.

Hi, maybe it is not working because the button doesn't exist when the event is added. You should move the event assignation inside the $(document).ready function.

@anayarojo OP's original question has the <script> at the end after the elements. I've added it back in for clarity

@D B since you are using jQuery, you can also use $("p").click(function()... you can see more information here https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_events.asp

Do you have any errors listed in your dev-tools Console? Perhaps you haven't included jQuery so your code that uses it causes an error

Why mix jQuery and native? Does logging addButton show it exists at that point?

@Phil There are no errors showing in my console.

@Phix I tried JQuery first.  i went native to try and see what I could get to work.

This is simply not reproducible. Your code runs just fine and alerts "clicked" when the button is pressed. To avoid having your question closed, please [edit] it to include a [mre] with particular focus on the reproducible part

There is no id="bulkSubmit" in the HTML you posted. But I don't see how that code could possibly interfere with adding the click listener to an unrelated button.

Thank you guys for the help. After stepping away for a day and looking at my code with fresh eyes, turns out I accidentally removed the line including the jQuery library.  Added that back in and it works.
